# cannot find checkbox control added on rowdatabound grid view even

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, postback

I have added control by

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.EnableViewState = true;
        chk.Enabled = true;
        chk.ID = "chkb";


        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        chk.Checked = (dr[0].ToString() == "true");


        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(chk);
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
    }
```

and trying to find by

```
     if (GridView2.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb =(CheckBox) GridView2.Rows[2].Cells[1].FindControl("chkb");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write("yest");
            }

        }
    }
```

But i cannot find it ...
Actually my problem is that i need to create a dynamic list.. for that i am using gridview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create dynamic controls on every postback since it is disposed at the end of the current life-cycle. But `RowDataBound` is just triggered when you databind the `GridView` what is done typically only `if(!IsPostBack)` (at the first time the page loads).

You should create dynamic controls in `RowCreated` instead which is called on every postback. You can databind these controls then in `RowDataBound` if you want, since `RowCreated` is triggered first.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.EnableViewState = true;
        chk.Enabled = true;
        chk.ID = "chkb";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(chk);
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkb");
        // databind it here according to the DataSource in e.Row.DataItem
    }
}
```

Comment: i am entering value in grid view using datatable on page load.. is there someway to generate new column for checkbox at page load or when should i create new column and how?

Comment: Sorry, your qustion is not clear and it's difficult to help via comments. Maybe you should ask another question. In general it's better and easier to modify the datasource(in this case the `DataTable`) to create all columns you need instead of creating columns or controls dynamically.

Comment: [new question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754276/generating-new-column-in-grid-view-for-checkbox-column) plz answer that question at this link