# generating new column in grid view for checkbox column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using datatable as data source for grid view

```
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Select",typeof(bool));


    //
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    //
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David");
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam");
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet");
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie");


    GridView2.DataSource = table;


    GridView2.DataBind();
```

at page load
and i want to create new column in grid to add radio button

actually i want to submit row values for selected check boxes in database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a new column to the `GridView` you should add it to it's `DataSource`. Either by selecting another column from the database or, if you use an in-memory `DataTable` as here- by adding another `DataColumn`. But i assume that you already have added the column(`Select`).

Then use a `TemplateField` to add the `RadioButton` and eval/bind it to the column.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" >
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelect"   runat="server" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

You can use `RowDataBound` to check it according to the datasource:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var rbSelect = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("rbSelect");
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        rbSelect.Checked = row.Field<bool>("Select");
    }
}
```

Comment: when i add radio button using item template.. then datatable cannot be added as data source which i need to bcz i am gonna add random rows there in a loop.

Comment: @InderpalSingh: You can use it as DataSource. Just set `AutoGenerateColumns=False` and add the `TemplateFields` or `BoundFields` for every column in the markup manually(like above). You can use `Eval` or `Bind` on the aspx markup to bind the data to the columns or set it programmatically from codebehind in `RowDataBound` as i've shown above.

Comment: thank you very much. i am gonaa add data to each column onRowDataBound.